# Aix grep wildcard not working

Tags: regex, grep, wildcard, ksh, aix

I have a file called **message** that has the line *CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/NONE/ORDRSP/758*

I am doing a grep (Platform is AIX 6.1)
`grep CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/NONE/ORDRSP/758 message`  it finds the line and displays the output

But, when I try to use wildcard as below 
`grep CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/.*/ORDRSP/758 message`
it is not finding the line.Am I missing anything here? I am confused.

Comment: Shouldn't matter, but maybe you need to put grep search target in single-quotes? i.e. `grep 'CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/.*/ORDRSP/758' message`. Also, this is not a programming question, in the future, please look to find the correct forum to post your question. Good luck.

Comment: Well, thanks @shellter I will move the question to different forum. Simply, the single-quotes is also not working for me!

Comment: Can you do: lslpp -h bos.rte.commands ?  Also, just for safety sake, can you do /usr/bin/grep ..... just to be sure you are getting the grep you think you should be.  I've experienced random failures with grep from time to time myself.  There may be a fix is the reason I'm asking for the lslpp level.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards in path names like this don't use regular expressions.  They use globbing instead.  In that scheme a dot is not a special character, so the command is looking for any directory with a name starting with that dot (which would be hidden, but that's another matter).  To search in any directory, just use the asterisk:

```
grep CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/*/ORDRSP/758 message
```